# Order of execution of SQL UPDATE while updating multiple values?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the sequence in which the values (separated by commas) will be updated?

```
$command = sprintf('UPDATE %s SET rating = ((rating * rating_count + %f) / (rating_count + 1.0)) , rating_count=rating_count+1 WHERE id=%d', $table, $ratingGiven, $id)`;
```

I want to make sure that

```
rating = (rating * rating_count + %f) / (rating_count + 1.0)
```

is executed before

```
rating_count=rating_count+1
```

without firing two SQL commands.

I am not sure if the update-value-statements are executed in the order in which they are separated by commas in MySql (or any other DB)?

Comment: I cannot see what difference it could make!?!

Comment: Upadte command is executed in order it is written like command coming right ofter `set` will execute first and other will be followed

Comment: Its the rating_count that would make a difference as it is being read in one statement and modified in the other.

Comment: There is only one statement.  See the comment I added to @Preet Sangha's answser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it will matter UPDATE  will read the current row and do the update upon it based on the existing  values, and not the ones that are in the update.

So in both SET operations, the original value of rating_count will be used.

Comment: Yes,  in very simplified terms the query is started, the database engine reads the values into memory, operates on them then writes them out.